# bitrise step to fetch provisioning profile from apple / hockey

Tags: xamarin.ios, hockeyapp, bitrise

I'm deploying an iOS/Xamarin app to Hockey with Bitrise

Is there a step or script anyone has written that will fetch the latest Hockey device id's, add them to the apple developers account, create a new provisioning profile, and download that to the bitrise workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No step so far, but feel free to create one, or just use a Script step and any tool you want to, to implement this flow.

You can find a guide about how you can install any custom / not preinstalled too at: https://bitrise-io.github.io/devcenter/tips-and-tricks/install-additional-tools/

Comment: After looking at this further the Hockey Api does not currently provide access to uploading provisioning profiles, so until it does, we're just running manually with it